# Product image don't show other image

Tags: javascript, html, image

Hi have a problem , i want to replicate the effect of this website :

http://riviera.sale/collections/flip-flop-collections

I have do all right except for the possibility **to change photo** ( 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 ) !!

This is my work at moment :

http://www.riviera-umirei.it/swimming.html

Someone could help me?

this is my HTML code :

```
<li class="product_image">
                    <a href="https://riviera.sale" data-largesrc="images/full/3c.jpg" data-title="Talloniera - Bianca" data-description="Morbida talloniera per pinne con cinturino.<br/> 46 x 14 x 31 cm <br/> ">
                       <div class="nohover">
                        <img src="images/thumbs/FLIPPERS-CLIPS03.jpg" alt="img15"/>
                        </div>

                    </a>
                </li>
```

and this is the HTML code of the store :

```html
<div class="container inner cf">


<div class="gallery layout-column-half-left has-thumbnails">
    <div class="main-image">
        
        <a href="/collections/flip-flop-collections/products/flip-flop-white">
            
                <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/1f_large.jpg?v=1434638964" data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/1f_large.jpg?v=1434638964" alt="FLIP FLOP White" style="opacity: 1;">
            
        </a>
        
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="thumbnails">
        Images
        
        
             / 
            <a class="active" title="FLIP FLOP White" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/1f_large.jpg?v=1434638964" data-full-size-url="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/1f.jpg?v=1434638964">
            
                <span>1</span>
            
        </a>
        
             / 
            <a title="FLIP FLOP White" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/flip1-bianca_large.jpg?v=1434638821" data-full-size-url="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/flip1-bianca.jpg?v=1434638821">
            
                <span>2</span>
            
        </a>
        
             / 
            <a title="FLIP FLOP White" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/flip2-bianca_large.jpg?v=1434638821" data-full-size-url="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/flip2-bianca.jpg?v=1434638821">
            
                <span>3</span>
            
        </a>
        
             / 
            <a title="FLIP FLOP White" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/flip3-bianca_large.jpg?v=1434638829" data-full-size-url="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0873/1162/products/flip3-bianca.jpg?v=1434638829">
            
                <span>4</span>
            
        </a>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Sorry the snippet is not complete, if is a problem i could try to complete it

Answer (score 0):

Go to the director `img/shopify.png` and search for image `shopify.png`, you image size is `0 byte` which mean it is corrupted. Replace it with new one.

Comment: I have not explained well, i want to have the possibility like in riviera.store to se other pictures when i click on the text 1 / 2 / 3 / 4